# Error when trying to build app in Xcode - "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: xcode, build, kivy

Trying to build my Kivy app in Xcode. Below are the code/snapshot of the specific errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ffi_tramp_alloc", referenced from:
      _ffi_closure_alloc in libffi.a(closures.o)
  "_ffi_tramp_free", referenced from:
      _ffi_closure_free in libffi.a(closures.o)
  "_ffi_tramp_get_addr", referenced from:
      _ffi_closure_alloc in libffi.a(closures.o)
      _ffi_data_to_code_pointer in libffi.a(closures.o)
  "_ffi_tramp_is_supported", referenced from:
      _ffi_closure_alloc in libffi.a(closures.o)
      _ffi_data_to_code_pointer in libffi.a(closures.o)
      _ffi_closure_free in libffi.a(closures.o)
      _ffi_tramp_is_present in libffi.a(closures.o)
      _dlmmap in libffi.a(closures.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]